# Why was my comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, deletion

I posted a comment on [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/38808/how-do-dna-binding-proteins-determine-that-theyre-binding-to-the-correct-dna-ba) question, which has mysteriously vanished. It wasn't exactly ground breaking, though it was certainly constructive. I'm curious why it's gone…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was not unconstructive but it was not very informative too. Moreover, it is obsoleted in the presence of the answer.

> Q: How do DNA-binding proteins determine that they're binding to the
>   correct DNA base pairs?
>
> C: The major groove contains more information and can distinguish between
>   C-G and G-C

If you disagree then I can undelete it. Comments are generally not used for answering (even if it is partial).

Comment: I was specifically addressing the statement in the OP that the minor groove cannot distinguish between base pairs. I don't really care that it was deleted; just seemed odd to me.

Comment: To me, the only reasons to delete a comment would be to clear up excessive clutter or overheated discussions, to remove clearly irrelevant comments or to remove suggestions for clarifications that have been addressed by the question/answer (but I think we should be restrictive about removing these as well). Overall, we don't have a big problem with excessive commenting, so I don't see the point of removing them?

Comment: @fileunderwater there are flags for obsolete comments. I agree that deleting this comment was not necessary (I actually undeleted it). In many sites such as TeX, people remove their comments as soon as the point is addressed. We seem to avoid excessive commenting by closing posts that attract a lot of comments :P

Comment: +1 many SEs need to treat comments this way.